# Python 3.6: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1'

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm trying to do this:

`str(field).encode('utf-8')`

field is a field from a pyodbc cursor row.

But I get this error:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 11

I can't drop any characters, so I cannot do "ignore"

I've got this at top of script:
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

I can't see what I'm missing, any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `field` and where does it come from?

Comment: field is a field from a pyodbc cursor row.